# Generalization of $y-x$ vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

I was wondering about, if we have two vectors $x=\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $y=\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} \in \Bbb R^2$, then $y-x=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

If we think about the subspace spanned by this $y-x$ vector, then we know it could be represented by the line along the $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ diagonal.

However, I’m wondering how this generalizes to higher dimensions. Imagine the $3 \times 2$ case, where $x$ and $y$ are both $3 \times 2$ matrices and would represent planes in three dimensional space. How do you represent the difference between the basis vectors? I imagine you can’t just look at $y-x$ because then you’re only looking at the difference between the first column of $y$ and the first column of $x$ and so on for the second column. I hope this idea makes sense, thanks if possible.

Comment: You have written $2\times1$ vectors there, not sure why you think they are not, unless you want to write them with parentheses instead in which case just switch bmatrix with pmatrix in your MathJaX.

Comment: In the question, $x$ starts as a vector but then it becomes a real number. This is not clear.

Comment: Hi Triatticus, sorry--you're right. When I'd written them on mobile they showed up as 1x2 vectors, but now the formatting is 2x1, so not sure what happened. I'll change the formatting Gribouillis so it makes more sense, thanks.

Comment: Note that the line spanned by the vector $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ has nothing whatsoever to do with the lines spanned by the two original vectors. The difference depends entirely on which vectors you pick in those two lines. So I'm not sure how this is at all a question about vector subspaces.

Comment: Hi Ted, no worries. I wasn't asking about the lines spanned by the original two vectors--but the line spanned by y-x (which would be the span of $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ in this case). I'm aware you could pick any y or x.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see your confusion. It may be helpful to go back to the definitions.

A set $V$ over the field $F$ equipped with the binary operations $+:(V \times V) \rightarrow V$ and $\cdot: (F\times V) \rightarrow V$ is said to be a vector space provided (the list of 8 criteria that you're probably familiar with). The elements of $V$ are called vectors and the elements of $F$ are called scalars.

So in the hypothetical you provided, where $V$ is the set of $3 \times 2$ matrices, the **matrices** are **vectors**. It doesn't really makes sense to say something like "the matrix represents planes in two dimensions", because the matrices are just vectors in the space.

Where you may be getting confused is that linear transformations can be represented by matrices, e.g. if $A$ is $3 \times 2$, it might act on vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and brings them to $\mathbb{R}^3$. In general, we can't say the geometric interpretation of this transformation is bringing two-space to two-space, since $A$ might very well take the plane to a line through the origin or to the origin itself.

Now to your question: **"How do you represent the difference between the basis vectors?"**

First you need to specifiy a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 2}$. A natural one might be:

$\Bigg\{\begin{gather*}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\end{gather*}\Bigg\}$

Then the difference between some basis vectors, say $e_1-e_2$, is just $\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$ as expected, and the subspace spanned by this vector is just $\begin{bmatrix}c & -c \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$ where $c\in F$ (presumably $F=\mathbb{R}$ here, though you could of course choose others).

Comment: Sorry will read through the rest of your comment, but just noticed I made a typo and meant to say planes in three dimensional space*. Really appreciate it